# Delete if image_id count is greater than 5?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have table

```
id color      image_id
1   red          2
2   green        2
3   pink         2
4   black        2
5   gray         2
6   orange       2
7   purple       2
8   yellow       2
9   greenish     2
10  white        2

select image_id,count(image_id) from colors group by image_id having count(image_id) > 5
```

if count is greater than 5 than delete data which is greater than 5.
for example

```
6   orange       2
7   purple       2
8   yellow       2
9   greenish     2
10  white        2
```

it should be deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to keep the first five rows for each image id.  Here is a method that uses variables:

```
delete i
    from images i join
         (select i.*,
                 (@rn := if(@id = id, @rn + 1,
                            if(@id := id, 0, 0)
                           )
                 ) as rn
          from images i cross join
               (select @id := 0, @rn := 0) vars
          order by image_id, id
         ) ii
         on ii.id = i.id 
    where ii.rn > 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a sub-query and then delete based on an inner join e.g. it will only delete the records where it has a join and in your sub-query you only bring back records that you want to delete..

```
delete a
from colors a
inner join
(
select image_id,count(image_id) from colors group by image_id having count(image_id) > 5
) as b
on a.image_id = b.image_id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
delete from colors
where id not in 
(select id
from colors 
order by id
limit 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following query will delete all image colors except the first 5 colors with the lowest color ids.

```
delete from colors where id in (
    select id from (
        select c1.id from colors c1
        join colors c2 on c1.image_id = c2.image_id and c2.id < c1.id
        group by c1.id
        having count(*) >= 5
    ) t1
)
```